# Recurse flag in get-childitem as string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to learn a bit of Powershell and have been converting a long archive script from Dos to Powershell. This has been working out quite well, but now I'm exploring options to rewrite the following part, if the field Recursive from an xml document is true, get-childitem has to use the -Recurse flag. Offcourse it would be nice if I could to this in one sentence, any ideas?:

```
if ($parameter.Recursive -eq "true")
        { $items = Get-ChildItem $parameter.ProcesDir -Recurse | where {!$_.PsisContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).adddays(-$parameter.Retention)}} 
    else 
        { $items = Get-ChildItem $parameter.ProcesDir | where {!$_.PsisContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).adddays(-$parameter.Retention)}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$recurse = if($parameter.Recursive -eq "true") {$true} else {$false}

$items = Get-ChildItem $parameter.ProcesDir -Recurse:$recurse | 
where {!$_.PsisContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).adddays(-$parameter.Retention)}
```

Comment: You could combine them using `-Recurse:($parameter.Recursive -eq "true")` if you really need a one-liner, but Shay's answer is easier to read :)

Comment: Yes, I preferred the easier to read over a one-liner. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: I agree. It's easier to maintain later when your script becomes larger. Variables like this don't cost much resources anyways :)

Comment: This is exactly what I need and very clear. Thank you very much, I appreciate it.